# Compiling embedded MATLAB functions in Simulink, Mac OSX 10.9 Mavericks, Xcode 5, MATLAB 2012b

Tags: matlab, xcode5, osx-mavericks, simulink

After I updated to the latest OSX Mavericks, I've had some issues compiling simple MATLAB function blocks in Simulink, like the diagram and the attached code below. [image: Simple Simulink diagram]

```
function y = fcn(t)
   %#codegen
   %Simple MATLAB .m function to be compiled with the diagram

y = sin(t)+cos(t);
```

I had the same problem under OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion, but I was able to solve the problem by downloading a Mathworks patch and following the instructions on [this site](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94092).

With the new OS and having upgraded to Xcode 5, I followed the instructions in [this post](http://www.imagetracking.org.uk/?p=73) to change the compiler and SDK info in my `mexopts.sh` file from

```
#PATCH: MacOSX10.8
        CC='llvm-gcc-4.2'
        CXX='llvm-g++-4.2'
        SDKROOT='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/'

        MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.8'
        ARCHS='x86_64'
```

to

```
#PATCH: MacOSX10.9
        CC='llvm-gcc'
        CXX='llvm-g++'
        SDKROOT='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/'

        MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.9'
        ARCHS='x86_64'
```

After running `mex -setup`and restarting MATLAB, I get the following error when trying to run a Simulink model with a function block (the behavior is the same for all models with these blocks):

```
Making simulation target "mextest_sfun", ... 


/Applications/MATLAB.app/bin/mex -c -O   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
-I/Applications/MATLAB.app/toolbox/stateflow/stateflow/../../../simulink/include 
-I/Applications/MATLAB.app/toolbox/stateflow/stateflow/../../../extern/include 
-I/Applications/MATLAB.app/stateflow/c/mex/include 
-I/Applications/MATLAB.app/stateflow/c/debugger/include   mextest_sfun.c
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated

/Applications/MATLAB.app/bin/mex -c -O   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
-I/Applications/MATLAB.app/toolbox/stateflow/stateflow/../../../simulink/include 
-I/Applications/MATLAB.app/toolbox/stateflow/stateflow/../../../extern/include 
-I/Applications/MATLAB.app/stateflow/c/mex/include 
-I/Applications/MATLAB.app/stateflow/c/debugger/include   mextest_sfun_registry.c
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated

/Applications/MATLAB.app/bin/mex -c -O   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
-I/Applications/MATLAB.app/toolbox/stateflow/stateflow/../../../simulink/include 
-I/Applications/MATLAB.app/toolbox/stateflow/stateflow/../../../extern/include 
-I/Applications/MATLAB.app/stateflow/c/mex/include 
-I/Applications/MATLAB.app/stateflow/c/debugger/include   c2_mextest.c
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated

/Applications/MATLAB.app/bin/mex -silent LDFLAGS="\$LDFLAGS " -output mextest_sfun.mexmaci64      mextest_sfun.o mextest_sfun_registry.o c2_mextest.o      /Applications/MATLAB.app/stateflow/c/mex/lib/maci64/sfc_mex.a /Applications/MATLAB.app/stateflow/c/debugger/lib/maci64/sfc_debug.a -L/Applications/MATLAB.app/bin/maci64 -lfixedpoint -lut -lmwmathutil -lemlrt -lmwblascompat32  -L/Applications/MATLAB.app/bin/maci64 -lippmwipt
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "sf_debug_api(int, mxArray_tag**, int, mxArray_tag const**)", referenced from:
  _mexFunction in mextest_sfun_registry.o
"_callCustomFcn", referenced from:
  _mdl_start_processing in sfc_mex.a(sfc_sf.o)
  _mdlTerminate in sfc_mex.a(sfc_sf.o)
"_sf_machine_global_initializer", referenced from:
  _mdl_start_processing in sfc_mex.a(sfc_sf.o)
 "_sf_machine_global_method_dispatcher", referenced from:
  _call_sf_machine_global_method_dispatcher in sfc_mex.a(sfc_sf.o)
"_sf_machine_global_terminator", referenced from:
  _mdlTerminate in sfc_mex.a(sfc_sf.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

mex: link of ' "mextest_sfun.mexmaci64"' failed.

gmake: *** [mextest_sfun.mexmaci64] Error 1
```

I'm thinking it's the `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` that is the key message here, but I really do not know. Have anyone had the same issues, or do anyone have a solution to this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to use `'clang'` and `'clang++'` in place of `'llvm-gcc'` and `'llvm-g++'`, but that shouldn't change anything. Is there a reason why the compiler in running "in C++ mode" on a bunch of C files? You should show your compile command. Can you compile any of the [example S-Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/example-of-a-basic-c-mex-s-function.html)? And have you included all of the correct headers?

Comment: What I am trying to compile here is a simple `.m` file in Simulink, so then I guess all the ´.c´ files listed in the error message are generated or at least called by the compiler or what ever. I'm sorry, I'm not really familiar with the mechanics behind these compilations. My point is, I don't know where to find the compile command, and I really don't know what headers to include, or that this would be necessary in the first place. I have now edited my question and included the Simulink diagram and the simple `.m` file, to make my problem somewhat clearer. Any tips would be of much help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the internet and waiting for answers on this forum with no results, the solution to my problem eventually became upgrading to MATLAB 2013a.

In addition, a little modification to the `mexopts.sh`file was needed. Just replace all instances of `10.7` to either `10.8` or `10.9`. Both of these worked for me, but I ended up replacing it with `10.9` as I'm running Mavericks.

The "official" solution to this can be found on [this site](http://www.mathworks.co.kr/matlabcentral/answers/87709).